# R: Extract matching string in dataframe column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a dataframe and a set of keywords. I want to create a new column in the dataframe that matches any of the strings in the keywords and a second dataframe with not-matching strings.

keyword <- c('yellow','blue','red','green','purple')

my dataframe

| colour | id |
| --- | --- |
| blue | A234 |
| blue,black | A5 |
| yellow | A6 |
| blue,green,purple | A7 |

What i hope to get is a dataframe like this:

| colour | id | match | non-match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | A234 | blue | yellow,red,green,purple |
| blue,green | A5 | blue,green | yellow,red,purple |
| yellow | A6 | yellow | blue,red,green,purple |
| blue,green,purple | A7 | blue,green,purple | yellow,red |

I tried this to get the match column:

```
df %>% mutate(match = str_extract(paste(keyword,collapse="|"), tolower(colour)))
```

but it only worked for the first and third rows, not the 2nd and 4th rows. Appreciate any help with this and also to get a column of unmatched strings.

Comment: Row 2 is blue,black in input data which changes to blue,green in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.  We can use `apply` in row mode, and split the CSV string of colors into a vector.  Then, use `%in%` to figure out what the non matching colors should be.

```r
df$match <- df$colour
df$non_match <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    paste(keyword[!keyword %in% strsplit(x[1], ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]], collapse=",")
})
df

             colour   id             match               non_match
1              blue A234              blue yellow,red,green,purple
2        blue,green   A5        blue,green       yellow,red,purple
3            yellow   A6            yellow   blue,red,green,purple
4 blue,green,purple   A7 blue,green,purple              yellow,red
```

**Data:**

```
keyword <- c('yellow','blue','red','green','purple')
df <- data.frame(colour=c("blue", "blue,green", "yellow", "blue,green,purple"),
                 id=c("A234", "A5", "A6", "A7"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: this really worked for my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get each `colour` in `separate_rows` splitting on comma and for each `id` you can find `match` using `intersect` and `non_match` with `setdiff`.

```
library(dplyr)
keyword <- c('yellow','blue','red','green','purple')

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(colour, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(match = toString(intersect(keyword, colour)), 
            non_match = toString(setdiff(keyword, colour)), 
            colour = toString(colour))

#  id    match               non_match                  colour             
#* <chr> <chr>               <chr>                      <chr>              
#1 A234  blue                yellow, red, green, purple blue               
#2 A5    blue                yellow, red, green, purple blue, black        
#3 A6    yellow              blue, red, green, purple   yellow             
#4 A7    blue, green, purple yellow, red                blue, green, purple
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(colour =c("blue","blue,black", "yellow", "blue,green,purple"
), id = c("A234", "A5", "A6", "A7")),class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```